# Programmatically adding Java app to startup

Tags: java, windows, linux, macos, startup

We're making a login client in Java for a school project.
It uses SSH to connect a local server to allow for internet connection, for the convinience of our users we would like to be able to make an "open on startup" function.

We know that this could be done by cron/damon jobs in linux, and by service/registry methods in windows... We don't know about OS X.

We would like to CODE the solution in java, each solution doesn't have to be for all 3 OS' but just one, then they can execute when needed.

Any help would be appriciated. :-)

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAJSW (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper) could provide this functionality, and is licensed under the LGPL.

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/

You'd want to create your configuration during installation I suppose, and in install/uninstall the service when the user toggles the checkbox.

You'll also find a feature matrix of other options for achieving the same thing at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId284533

And for you interest, under the hood on OS X the system this uses is called [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Java Service Wrapper, which also support launchd on OS X. Furthermore run a Java application as Windows Service or on Linux using init.d/upstart.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/launch-nix.html#boot

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Best Regards,
Chrisitan

Comment: As far as i can see the wrappers community edition is free...  Seems confusing though... Thanks

Comment: Free, yes, but licensed under GPL, so you can not distribute it with commercial software unless everything is also placed under GPL. JSW was the go-to choice for many years, when it was under a more liberal license, but many other options have appeared since it switched to GPL.